# Unable to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

When attempting to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 by executing the following:

`sudo do-release-upgrade -d -f DistUpgradeViewGtk3`
or 
`sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

I receive the following message

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

I have no issues with DNS I am able to ping `changelogs.ubuntu.com` with no significant latency. 
I have modified `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` from Normal to LTS and back again with no change in error.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Be aware the Linux often is case sensitive, and the description in release-upgrades says "normal" and "lts" .. all in lower case. If this doesn't change anything, try running `sudo apt update` to verify that communication with servers work. And, cby the way, if it says that updates are available run `sudo apt upgrade`. Update your question with anything of this that fails.

Comment: I get the same response when i try 'sudo do-release-upgrade -d' Feels like this is for development upgrades of the LTS and we need to find a utility that upgrades to the production release?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did use the -d option, 'Failure to connect' indicates everyone else and their second cousin are also trying to upgrade.

Patience is a virtue; use this time to make a backup of your system to an external drive or cloud, and verify the backup matches the source files; then, make another backup to a different external drive or different cloud, and verify that.

Comment: I would be willing to accept that as a possibility but the entire message contains the message  "Check your Internet connection or proxy settings" That would seem to me to indicate that it is failing to connect to the site.